# Div Float with Image

Tags: css, html, css-float, image

When I float a div with text it in the behavior is what I want but when I put an image inside, the float dosen't behave the same way and the image then goes down one line. Why is that?

Comment: can you post your code? try floating the image

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe you could post code markup and perhaps a screenshot to help us understand this problem. When you're done that please flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Put the image before the text if you want the text on the right side of the img.
to make sure the text flows to the right of the img float:left.

```
<div  style="float:left;">
<img src="someimg" style="float:left;"/>
<p>Text will pop on right</p>
</div>
```

if you first want text then image

```
<div  style="float:left; width:200px;">
<p style="width:80% float:left;">Text will pop on left</p>
<img src="someimg" style="width:20%"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dug these up from my favorites as they've helped me in the past. Galchen is right - we need some markup / CSS to better understand your issue.

The Image might go down if it's being set to a block element in a style - which would do this.

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

http://www.tizag.com/cssT/float.php